# Matplotlib: Adding axhline to subplot within Figure object

Tags: python, matplotlib, mne-python

I need to find a way how to reference axes within `matplotlib.figure.Figure` object in order to add axhline(s) to one of the plots. I am using a [plot_joint](https://mne.tools/stable/generated/mne.Evoked.html#mne.Evoked.plot_joint) from the package MNE to create an EEG butterfly plot with a couple of topoplots. The lines will serve to showcase windows of statistical significance in the butterfly plot. Thanks!

Comment: `fig.axes[0].axhline(...)`

Comment: I have tried this before (using y, xmax, ymax args). It prints out `<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x2d118470>` but fig.show() shows the same old plot. Any idea what might went wrong?

Comment: No, but that's no wonder without seeing any code.

Comment: Sure, will have to try to simulate some data later. With EEG it is always a bit pain. Anyways, thanks for now.

Comment: It could help to add `zorder=3` (or some higher number) to force the lines to be shown on top of the rest of the image. Also, take care that in [`axhline(y=0, xmin=0, xmax=1)`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axhline.html) the `y` is expressed in the data units of the y-axis, while the `xmin` and `xmax` go from 0 to 1, from left to right.

Comment: @ayasugihada A first step could be to show the code without the data. And give a good description how the data looks like.

Comment: Marvelous, zorder seems to have solved the issue. Thanks a ton JohnC!

Answer (score 0):

Either of these 2 should work, depends on your setup of figure and axes:

`fig.axes[0].axhline(...)`

OR

`ax.axhline(...)`

credit to @ImportanceOfBeingErnest for the inspiration